# Ignore rewrite for specific directory

Tags: .htaccess, apache-1.3

Running apache 1.3 (don't ask)
Need to redirect `mydomain.com/bla` to `mydomain.com/bla/` (note the slash)

I think this rewrite is writing it to the wrong place.

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/?$          index.php?page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

I have tried to ignore it but this hasn't worked.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/bla
RewriteRule ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Your explanation is a bit confusing, but is it the trailing slash you want to add to every directory URL? So `/bla` becomes `/bla/` and `/files` becomes `/files/` and so on? You can do that with this mod_write configuration:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

The second line excludes all (existing) regular files, the third line excludes all URL's which already have a trailing slash and the last line tells mod_rewrite to redirect the visitor to the specified domain followed by the original path, but now with a trailing slash.